# ajax call for event calendar

Tags: php, ajax

i am working on events calendar.i want to retrieve a event from database when a specific date is clicked in the calendar.
Also i need to highlight the data which has event information.please help me with the code

Comment: Post some code if you have. Or are you looking for the code?

Comment: i am sorry.i am looking for the code .i have only designed a calendar.

Comment: We can't help you like that! Google for the code,play with it and if something goes wrong,come back with your doubts and we'll help you

Comment: i have done same in one facebook app url = http://apps.facebook.com/whereill  . try add 5+ schedule on different dated of different months .u need exactly like that.if you like that i will post my Code for you.the app is old enough i think its live

Comment: Please explain how you designed calender by using some plugin etc.

Comment: @Deadlock no i have not used any plugin. i have made it through JavaScript

Comment: i have used date picker plugin

Comment: than you to do a lot to customize that :(

Answer (score 0):

Do ajax call on date clicked

```
var date = $('#dateid').val();
    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: url,       
                        data: 'date=date ',
                        success:function(msg)
                        {       
                           //here you can play whatever you want

                        }
                    });
```

In your php file

Get the date `$_POST['date']` and write the query and return the date,

Answer (score 0):

You may try **Easy PHP Calendar** rather than writing entire Code when you already have the resources available.

http://www.easyphpcalendar.com/demoStandard7.php

For a **Free Version** Try [Calendarix](http://www.calendarix.com/download_basic.php) or [WebCalendar](http://webcalendar.sourceforge.net/demo/month.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [This Event Calendar](http://www.webappers.com/2010/06/08/wdcalendar-jquery-based-google-calendar-clone/), may be this can help you.